# elasticsearch Flush latency

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, zabbix

a cluster of 3 nodes in docker is configured, in front of elasticsearch there is nginx, which proxies to 3 elasticsearch nodes

after switching from version 6.8 to 7.12.1 in Zabbix the trigger worked - "Flush latency is too high" and the graph shows that it is constantly growing, what could be the problem? how can this be fixed?[image]

Comment: you are probably looking at the latency total/sum. Try using "change per second" or "simple change" preprocessing.

Comment: @IronBishop this is not a total latency graph for all servers, the graph shows data for one server

Comment: @IronBishop if that were the case, how would it go down occasionally?